# android textview line break between . and "

Tags: android, textview, newline, line-breaks

I have a sentence in quotation marks like "I have a sentence in quotation marks.". If the sentence is just a bit too long for my textview the sentence gets broken between the dot and the quotation mark, which looks ugly. In total I have some hundred sentences so if I change the size or the device it will happen to other sentences. Is this a bug? Does anyone have a solution how to fix this?

thanks

"This is another longer description."
"This is the sentence."

first one looks ok, like this:
"This is another longer
description."

second one like this:
"This is the sentence.
"

Comment: try android:maxEms="10".

Comment: You can implement TextWatcher interface and implement method afterTextChanged. The method will be invoked after text changed, so you can add the line breaks in it by yourself. You can also make the TextView Horizontally scrollable to avoid line break.

Comment: I have a list with words of the day. If you select a word then only this word is diplayed on a screen with a description in quotation marks. so the textview never changes but gets populated with descriptions of different lengths every time you select a word

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you increase the size of your TextView by 1dp, but if that isn't an option, you can just set maxLines = 1.

Comment: thanks, but if I change the size, then the sentences where the problem occured will work, but other sentences will show this problem.